# EC2 instance becomes unresponsive when all the pods are used and other chrome nodes are in queue

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks, selenium-grid, autoscaling

I have created an EKS cluster to run my Selenium Tests. So the structure is - I have setup selenium grid using the .yaml files and that connection is working fine. I have implemented HPA which adds the chrome nodes if the CPU utilization goes above 70%. I have also added ASG which will add new instance if the CPU utilization of the instance goes above 70%. I have used t3.medium EC2 instance and it has maximum of 17 pods. Now what happens when I run my selenium script with 60 parallel sessions all the 17 pods are utilized and the instance becomes unresponsive and the status shown is "Unknown", as per the configuration it should add new instance and run the chrome nodes but that doesn't seem to be happening.
Can anyone point me if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: beware that scaling up nodes takes some time.

Comment: yes, but the current instance becomes unresponsive and gets terminated. I am not sure why

Comment: probably because it has too high CPU utilization.

Comment: I checked CPU usage and it is within 70%